# Why does my UIImage not display in a routine other than ViewDidLoad()?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7, uiimageview, uiimage

I am running XCOde 5, ios7.
I created a UIImage in the Storyboard.
If I set the .image property using:
`self.image43.image = [UIImage imageNamed:self.string4];`

in `ViewDidLoad()`, it **WORKS FINE!**

If, however, execute the exact same code inside my gameplay routine (the routine have setup as my timer selector as shown below), **it does not display**.

`self.myTImer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/30.0 target:self selector @selector(gameplay:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES`

I'm sooooo close to being done..... :)

THanks
-Ed

Comment: Where have you written self.myTImer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/30.0 target:self selector @selector(gameplay:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES this code?

Comment: show us your gameplay: method

Comment: Make sure you are setting the image on the main thread.  That could be your problem.

Comment: My timer statement above is in the ViewDidLoad.  Gameplay is way to big to paste here... there are other labels which I change and they work just fine.   I guess I'm having trouble with the concept of "main thread".    ViewDidLoad creates a timer which calls "gameplay" every 30th of a second.   gameplay simply manipulates label text, visibility and sounds.   Can someone help me understand what is considered a "main thread" ?